# Delete specific element from XML file using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Quick question--I'm having trouble with the xml manipulation syntax in VB.net. My xml file is very simple. Here is an example:

```
<C_Clients>
    <client>208</client>
</C_Clients>
```

I have the ability to add a new "client" using a textbox and a button, however I need to be able to remove a specific element that is placed in the textbox as well.

Comment: there are several ways to achieve that. Post codes you have to add new "client". What did you use `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
Dim xml = <C_Clients>
            <client>208</client>
            <client>209</client>
          </C_Clients>
Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(xml.ToString)
Dim clientNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//client")
For Each elem As Xml.XmlElement In clientNodes
  If elem.InnerText = textbox1.Text Then
    elem.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem)
    Exit For
  End If
Next
MessageBox.Show(doc.OuterXml)
```